# Consecutive integers each of which has a large prime factor

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization, integer-sequences

There are many results about consecutive integers all having small prime factors. But what about consecutive integers each of which has a large prime factor?

More precisely, let $P(n)$ be the greatest prime factor of $n$.

Is it true that for each $k \geq 1$ there exists $n \geq 1$ such that $P(n + i) > \sqrt{n + i}$ for all $i=1,\dots,k$ ?

If yes, what is an upper bound in terms of $k$ for the least possible $n$ ?

Comment: Ooops, I'd better delete that comment :)

Comment: fine for $k=2$ with Chinese Remainder Theorem. For $k \geq3,$ need to get a better search for nearly consecutive $p_j$ such that $ n \equiv -1 \pmod p_1, $  $ n \equiv -2 \pmod p_2, $ $ n \equiv -3 \pmod p_3.$ but $n$ is especially small. I'd say it is already worth trying $k=3$ by computer, see how difficult it might be.

Comment: You might check out https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255269 (of which this question is almost a duplicate) and similar questions. My belief is that not much is known, and that your upper bound on n will be exponential in k, and that proving this is hard.  Gerhard "But Go Check For Yourself" Paseman, 2019.02.25.

Comment: @Will, for k=3 my computer says n=4. For k=5 my computer says n=18.  Gerhard "Check OEIS For Bigger Numbers" Paseman, 2019.02.25.

Comment: Consider the following dynamic on positive integers: n goes to n/P(n)  and 1 goes to 1.  Every n reaches 1 in about log log n steps (with some exceptions). Call n quite rough if at every step P(n_i) is larger than the square root of n_i. So primes, products of two distinct primes, and 42 are quite rough. What is the density/distribution of quite rough numbers? I suspect a question post about this hasn't appeared on MathOverflow. Can you show there is no sequence of 4 consecutive numbers which are all quite rough? Gerhard "Feel Free To Ask It" Paseman, 2019.02.25.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman thank you. If you can stand it, please go a bit higher, increase $k$ in a loop until it slows down. I'm busy today, ill and I need to arrange the apartment so the handyman can check my stove, water heater, and wall hanging room heater for possible CO emissions, in any case service the wall heater, which is old

Comment: (112 120)  (650 660) (1105 1116) are intervals of rough numbers, gotten from visually scanning the text file for OEIS sequence 63539. I may write a program later today. My program for Happy New Prime Year (50691) can be tweaked to check for this sequence though, if you feel like tweaking AWK. Gerhard "Hoping You Feel Better Soon" Paseman, 2019.02.25.

Comment: I see now in a comment to 255269 that I ran such a program and provided partial results (so replace (650 660) by (364 374)) with an interval of 40 rough numbers somewhere below 27 million.  Gerhard "Is K Big Enough Now?" Paseman, 2019.02.25.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman  thanks. I decided to finish arranging the apartment, so I did not notice this until now. Good work.